# AngularJS - Get Key of Selected Object When ng-options is an Object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a `<select>` with ng-options defined by an object. ng-model captures the selcted object, but I want to also capture the key that was selected. I haven't been able to find a way to do that. Here's an html snippet.

```
<select class="form-control" id="xaxis" ng-model="model.xaxis" ng-options="k for (k,v) in model.options"></select>
```

Here's an example of the model.options object:

```
$scope.model.options = {
  "power":{"label":"blah","values":[],"color":"red"},
  "voltage":{"label":"blah","values":[],"color":"blue"}
}
```

If I select "power", my `ng-model` variable becomes `{"label":"blah","values":[],"color":"red"}`. I want to also capture, the key `"power"` as a scope variable. How would one do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the key values instead, that way you can easily access data in your controller using $scope.model.options[$scope.model.xaxis].